# hive llap with node label

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn

i have a hortonworks 3.1 cluster. Originally, i had 6 data nodes, 3 master nodes, the 6 data nodes all have 96gb of memory. I was able to spin up 3 llap nodes just fine. now i have 3 new nodes, 256gb of memory, i want to use those for the llap nodes now.

I added a node label "llap" to the 3 new nodes. then i assigned the llap queue that same label. (all other nodes are default label)

for some reason, when i start up llap, i get the following error:
Failed: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Component llap: specified memory size (224256) is larger than configured max container memory size (94208)

i've tried everything i can think of, but it seems that llap want to spin things up on the old node, not the new one...

i've googled my life away, but i keep finding the same refrences from cloudera / hortonworks, which i've messed with over and over and over again... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the configuration parameter of YARN which determines the maximum container size:

- `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`

In your case you, you are trying to alocate to a single container 224256MB, your configuration of `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` is 94208MB.

There is a very good article detailing how to setup your LLAP configuration:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/LLAP-sizing-and-setup/ta-p/247425

Comment: i've ready that article. my problem is i have a couple nodes that have more memory than the rest ( for example, my data nodes have 96gb, and my llap nodes have 256gb) so i want all of the llap services to run on the appropriate nodes. here's another reference i've made on the cloudera site [link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-LLAP-on-specific-nodes/m-p/282688#M210139)